# Powershell runspace multihreading / PoshRSJob

Tags: powershell

I am looking at using the PoshRSJob as I would like to multithread a large scale SharePoint migration job I am doing. I am a little confused about setting this up, having followed some introductory posts:

I have the following code:

```
1..50 | ForEach { Start-RSJob -Name “SP Migration" -Throttle 5 -ScriptBlock{
Actual code here
} }
```

Is the `1..50` in the pipeline the number of runspaces provisioned? And are these a thread each? Also, what does the throttle parameter mean?
Thanks!

Comment: sadly tats the part missing from https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxgrI58XiKnDDByjhRJs5fg

Comment: btw, why don't you ask the author? https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob

Comment: my guess would be 1 to 50 is what has to be done. throttle 5, the number of runspaces

Comment: The throttle defines the number of runspaces which will ever be used for the RSJobs and they are reused rather than recreated each time. The `1..50` means that at the very beginning you will have 5 jobs running and 45 queued up to run and as a job finishes, another will take its place until all have completed.

Comment: Ok perfect. I want to multi-thread a block of code so I am guessing the code in the brackets will get multi-threaded and I don't need to pipe a function in? Apologies I am the original poster but I don't have my account credentials on this machine.

Comment: Just realised you're the author of the code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
1..50 | %{ Start-RSJob -Name “SP Migration" -Throttle 5 -ScriptBlock{ Actual code here } }
```

`1..50` is an array of numbers from 1 to 50.

`| %` pipes the array into a `Foreach-Object` (`%` is an alias of `Foreach-Object`).

The outer `{` ... `}` brackets are the anonymous function called for each iteration of the Foreach-Object.

`-Throttle 5` limits RSJob to 5 threads.

The inner `{` ... `}` brackets are where you'd put your SharePoint code to handle each thread.

You'd also replace `1..50` with the array/collection you want to multi-thread.